# Add custuom header according to the url path

Tags: header, haproxy, traefik

I'm finding a way to add a custom header according to the url path in haproxy or traefik.

by example:
For a url: http://domain/toto/app, I want the reverse-proxy add a header: somekey=toto before it sends to the back service.

thanks

update : in my example, /toto is a dynamic value, it is only konwn at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to add a header for the request to the backend service.

- [http-request add-header](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20add-header)
- [http-request set-header](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20set-header)

It depends if the header is already exist or not which directive you can use.

Comment: thanks. but I cant find a way to add a header with a value dynamic.

Comment: what do you mean with "dynamic"? Maybe you can put more details into the question.